# mySQL - select unique values in two columns

Tags: mysql, select, unique, distinct

I really can't find a simple or even any solution via sql to get unique data from DB (mySQL).

I will give a sample (simplified):

TABLE t

```
fruit  | color  | weight
-----------------------
apple  | red    | 34
kiwi   | red    | 23
banana | yellow | 100
kiwi   | black  | 3567
apple  | yellow | 23
banana | green  | 2345
pear   | green  | 1900
```

And now I want output - something like distinct(apple) and distinct(color) together and order by 
weight desc:

```
kiwi   | black  | 3567
banana | green  | 2345
apple  | red    | 34
```

- pear | green // is not ok, becouse green is already "used"
- banana | yellow // is not ok, becouse banana is already "used"

So I need not only group by fruit, but also color (all unique).

Any advice or solution? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to want distinct color but your example result seems to make completely arbitrary decisions as to how the color is selected. You need at least one more requirement such as unique color that are lightest or heaviest.

Comment: Paul, sorry, I was editing text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear why banana|green is preferred to banana|yellow (change `RIGHT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` for tastier fruit) so I hope I've understood what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT t1.fruit, t1.color, t1.weight
FROM
t AS t1
RIGHT JOIN
(
SELECT fruit, color, weight
FROM t
GROUP BY 
color
) AS t2
ON
t1.fruit = t2.fruit AND t1.color = t2.color
GROUP BY fruit
ORDER BY weight DESC;
```

Also please be aware how MySQL handles [hidden columns in GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fruit, color, weight 
FROM t
GROUP BY fruit, color
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

Comment: This is not correct. I said you need to look both columns not just one. Look example once more.